# PostgreSQL - to_char for timestamp Don't Display Microseconds If Zero

Tags: postgresql

I am converting a timestamp with timezone to an ISO format:

```
select to_char('2020-01-01T20:20:03.000000000Z'::timestamptz, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.US"Z"');
```

In this case, the microseconds are all zero. How can I specify in the format to not display these and the leading `.` if there are no microseconds in the timestamp?

Or is there a better way entirely to format timestamps with timezone in ISO format?

Comment: 1) The only thing you are doing is converting a `timestamptz` type to a string type. 2) No, if you ask for `US` you will get them zero padded as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to_char` function requires a single format parameter, but what you are asking requires a different depending on the value from microseconds. So you cannot do this directly. You can, however, use `case` to select the appropriate format. This can be done within the `case` as the second parameter. So: (assuming column `ts`)

```
select to_char(ts 
              ,case when mod(extract (microseconds from ts),1000000) = 0 
                    then 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'
                    else 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.US"Z"'
               end 
             ) "Timestamp"
  from <table_name>;
```

Instead of putting `case` as a parameter in `to_char` it seems more straight forward and easier to read using `to_char` within `case`:

```
select case when mod(extract (microseconds from ts),1000000) = 0 
            then to_char(ts,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')
            else to_char(ts,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.US"Z"')
       end "Timestamp"
  from <table_name>;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/SvVuOUTw). Also see documentation for the [extract()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function.